# benefits of using headers?

Tags: php, json, jsonp

What are the benefits of using headers in php? I am working on rest based web services.

and for JSON what headers are necessary? What are the advantages of headers?

Comment: Are you trying to ask "what kind of data should I put in an HTTP request header to pass to my web service, as opposed to using a path or query parameter?" ?

Comment: The environment that you are using is supplying default values for some of the headers.  If you are happy with defaults you need not supply any of your own values.  Which headers should you use?  Depends on how much advantage you want to take of HTTP.  Go to a [list of HTTP request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests) and see if any make sense for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One use can be to tell the browser what kind of media the response is. In your case, you could tell the browser not to cache the response and what kind of media it is.

For exmple :

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

You can also use header to know what if the request is ajax. Another use  which is really important in your case is to know the request type post, get, delete or what have you.

Answer (score 5):

> What are the benefits of using headers for JSON?

JSON has no concept of anything called a "header"

> I am working on rest based web services. So for that are headers necessary?

REST is HTTP. HTTP requests and responses must have headers. HTTP can't work without them.

> what are the advantages of using it?

You can't have a working HTTP system without them.